# Preciso salvar parâmetros em várias tabelas

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

Estou retornando alguns parâmetros e preciso desmembrar esses parâmetros salvando em duas tabelas.

Segue o código inicial:

lamina.controller.js

```
    function salvar() {

        // remove a mensagem de sucesso
        delete vm.lamina.sucesso;

        // passando o valor sem o R$ e transformando para inteiro
        var valorAplicacao = vm.valor.replace('R$ ', '').split(".").join("").replace(',', '.');
        valorAplicacao = parseFloat(valorAplicacao);

        // data e hora atual
        let data = new Date();
        var dataBase = data.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}Z$/, '');

        // salva os dados na PRIMEIRA TABELA (funcionando)
        var simulacao = {

        //GRAVAR DADOS NA TABELA SIMULACAO
            cpfCnpj : vm.cpfcnpj,                   
            valorAplicacao : valorAplicacao,
            indice : indice.value.replace('string:',''),
            tipoPessoa : vm.tipoPessoa,
            dataBase : dataBase,

        //GRAVAR DADOS NA TABELA RESPOSTA INVESTIDOR
            coPergunta : "2",                   
            coResposta : "6" ,
            coSimulacao : "15", 

        };
        LaminaService.save(simulacao).then(function() {
            vm.lamina.sucesso = vm.messageService.getA('MA005');
        });

    }
```

lamina.service.js

```
        /**
     * Salva as simulações
     */
    function save(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        return $http.post(url, obj);
    }
```

LaminaResource.java

```
    /**
 * Grava a simulação
 * 
 * @param simulacao
 * @return Response
 */
@POST
public Response update(Simulacao simulacao) {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    simulacaoService.save(simulacao);

    return Response.ok(response).build();
}


/**
 * Grava a resposta investidor
 * 
 * @param simulacao
 * @return Response
 */
@POST
public Response update(RespostaInvestidor simulacao) {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    respostaInvestidorService.save(simulacao);

    return Response.ok(response).build();
}
```

SimulacaoService.java

```
        public Simulacao save(Simulacao simulacao) {
    if (simulacao.getId() == null) {
        return simulacaoRepository.insert(simulacao);
    } else {
        return simulacaoRepository.update(simulacao);
    }

}
```

Comment: Certo, e qual é o erro ?